# Combobox inside data-aware cxgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tcxgrid

I have a data-aware cxgrid connected to a toracledataset object.

Inside the DB is a column defined as number(1,0) to allow boolean values.

I want to format the corresponding grid column as ComboBox to give the user the ability to choose between the two options.

How can I cast the string inside the combobox to the integer value that will be inserted in the DB?
I know how to do that with a regular combobox, but not inside a cxgrid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way will be to use a cxEditrepositiory
add a cxImageComboBox
add Items and define Value and Valuetype
this then can be choosen for your GridColum.RepositoryItem

Comment: Should have thought about that :(